# What is the etymology of "look out"?

Tags: etymology, sense-verbs

What does English idiom "look out" (or "watch out") come from? When you want to warn somebody.

Usually, in case of a danger, it is better to hide rather than move your head out to see.

(I know it is an idiom, but maybe there is some reason in it)

Comment: But you don't know there is danger unless you look out for it.

Comment: Voictus, welcome and -1! I don't think "watch out" carries the sense of immediateness, so in the very moment one hears "watch out" they don't have to hide, but, rather, have the need of being aware and on guard for something or someone.

Comment: Hi Carlo, we meet again :) but why -1? This is mainly etymology question, so my thinking might be wrong, but how could I improve it?

Comment: Voitcus, no research efforts. If there is a specific idiom or expression you want expert help to understand, please edit to show prior research and rephrase the question. Thank you.

Comment: This is an idiom, but it's a standard idiom. **All** phrasal verbs are idiomatic, after all. And the difference between _look out_ and _watch out_ is the same as the difference between _look_ and _watch_, so there's no real etymology here. And a good thing, because etymology isn't normally done on phrasal verbs.

Comment: Phrasal verbs just _are_. 'Sit up' is not the opposite of 'Sit down'. I don't think there are etymologies that follow their provenance as a whole but it would be fascinating to to see. That is, I don't think there's an answer to this particular question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Look out***

[**Definition**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/look+out)
*To be watchful or careful*; *take care, be vigilant, be on the lookout or be careful*; "Watch out for pickpockets!"

[**Look out**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lookout)
*origin* 1690–1700; noun use of verb phrase look out

[**Etymology**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lookout&searchmode=none): **Lookout** (n) also look-out, "person who stands watch or acts as a scout," 1690s, from look + out.

*Verbal phrase* **look out** "be on the watch" attested from c.1600.

It appears that the phrasal verb expression *look out* originates from the noun lookout (one word) which meant ....

[image]

Source Century Dictionary: http://www.global-language.com/CENTURY/